# Data not loading in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

I have started ElasticSearch, Logstash (3 conf files - input file, filter file and output file) and kibana server.

The input file :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/zakir/Downloads/access.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

The filter file is:

```
filter {
  if [path] =~ "access" {
    mutate { replace => { "type" => "apache_access" } }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}
```

Output file is :

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Run Logstash : sudo service logstash restart

---

the data is not loading in kibana .. I was getting data sometime ago - suddenly i am not able to view the data in kibana..

can anyone help me to figure out this issue

Comment: Try changing your time range: http://prntscr.com/9oq8os

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Can you be little specific, Are you talking about timestamp in filter file?

Comment: No, I'm talking about time range in Kibana. Here's a better picture: http://prntscr.com/9oqc0y Just pick something like *This week* or *This month*

Comment: What if you set `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` in your `file` input plugin?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Thank you It worked

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this wasn't even a problem. [Soundarya Thiagarajan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4998626/soundarya-thiagarajan) wasn't aware of default Kibana time range (last 15 minutes).

Changing index time span to a wider range fixed issue:

[image]